# How to run Flutter legacy library?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, flutter-test, dart-pub

Flutter_Blue 0.8.0 Its library is not compatible with the version of Flutter I am using.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/versions/0.7.3 How do I install this ? Pub dont work. Or why the Flutter_Blue package is not working for me. flutter_bluetooth_serial okey
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a lower version of the package, you can lower the SDK version.
Flutter 1.x version https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases